# heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i'm deployed my app to heroku. i can push it successfull .but when run heroku open it show errors :

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
```

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

and then i use command heroku logs it show error as shown bellow :

```
...
2014-07-27T01:18:25.726069+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=********.herokuapp.com request_id=1ded5a34-7d01-440b-9fb4-0041fdc64715 fwd="110.74.222.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

please hepl me !

Comment: what does it say immediately *before* that?

Comment: Do you have a page set as root.  I think it is looking for the route that would show up as "www.yoursitename.com\"  but if no page is root it won't land there.

Comment: yes in router.rb i set root :to =>'homes#index' as default load page

Comment: Could you post your config/routes.rb and also more (or all) of the error log?

Answer (score 1):

It could happen because of several reasons,

try

```
heroku run console
```

it should show you the exact error.
in my case there was a problem in application.rb file in the configuration folder.

did you do something special in you app ? did you removed ActiveRecord ? are you using some specific gem ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution in my case, add in the gemfile the last version of pg gem, just like that:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
```

I hope you work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about Rails yet to know if this is of help but I am working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (6th edition) and encountered this error. Looking at the log file showed an error in the User.rb class and indicated a problem with two lines that the tutorial had suggested adding for content validation. I commented out the two lines and redeployed to Heroku and it ran fine. I uncommented the two lines and deployed again and the error was present. Here is the listing of the class.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :microposts
      #validates FILL_IN, presence: true # replace FILL_IN with the rightcode.
      #validates FILL_IN, presence: true # replace FILL_IN with the rightcode.     
end
```